# React Router Redux always show first route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-redux

React router redux always show the first route. No matter which url i entered, it will render the first route.

**Index.js file**

```
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
   <App />
</ConnectedRouter>
```

**App.js file**

```
export default function App() {
      return (
            <Switch>
              <Route to="/" component={Dashboard} key={1} />;         
              <Route to="/icons" component={Icons} key={2} />;         
           </Switch>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Anyways why are you using connectedRouter as it is not being maintained now.

Comment: i am using react-boilerplate, they've used connectedRouter instead Router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add exact={true} to Route, default exact is set to false, just take a look [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4958).

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} key={1} />;
```

Comment: i did <Route exact to="/" component={Dashboard} key={1} />; 
but still it does not make a difference. Both routes "/" & "/icons" show "Dashboard" component :(

Comment: Just replace to with path, path to means redirect to another route... flag to is mostly used in 404 or something like that

Comment: replacing to with path does the trick, but there is still an issue, if i set path = "/dashboard" it work, but when i set path = "/" it does not work :/

Comment: done, 1st. changed connectedRouter to BrowserRouter. 2nd. replace to with path. 3rd. placed "/" at the end of routes list

Answer (score 2):

When you make use Switch, you need to add the Routes, whose paths are prefixes to other Routes at the end since Switch matches and renders the first route that matched.

```
export default function App() {
      return (
            <Switch>
              <Route to="/icons" component={Icons} key={2} />
              <Route to="/" component={Dashboard} key={1} />              
           </Switch>
      );
    }
```

And you don't need `;` at the end of JSX statements

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the bad route configuration in your example. You need to add **exact** prop to the first route.

Example:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact to="/" component={Dashboard} />;         
    <Route to="/icons" component={Icons} />;         
</Switch>
```

If you don't add exact to the "/" route, then it will always be matched, because every other route also has the / as its part.

My suggestion is to define all routes as exact by default, and only set non-exact routes when required such as:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact to="/" component={Dashboard} key={1} />;         
    <Route exact to="/icons" component={Icons} key={2} />;  
    <Route to="/icons/:iconId" component={IconDetails} key={3} />;       
</Switch>
```

Comment: i did <Route exact to="/" component={Dashboard} key={1} />; and  <Route exact to="/icons" component={Icons} />;    but still it does not make a difference. Both routes "/" & "/icons" show "Dashboard" component :(

Comment: What router exactly are you using. React-router-dom or react-router ? Which versions ? Also, try with the normal Router, instead of Connected one because connectedrouter is used for isomorphic apps, where node.js expressjs would for example handle the routing for you.

Comment: React-router-dom 4.3.1
Tried with normal Router from React-router-dom still no luck :(
i can share github code can you help me there